# c stdin 2d array file input

Tags: c, stdin, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to take a file that is designed to look like a maze and create a 2d array using stdin. I'm not sure how I start with this. I have the 2d array created, but I'm not sure on the function call. I think I would use two for loops to traverse the file and then store the element into the array. I don't have any code to give right now because I'm pretty lost on how to start this.

```
T . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . T . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . T . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . T . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . T . .
. . . . T . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . T . . . . . . . . . . . .
T . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . T . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . T . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . T . . . . T . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . T . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
F . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

This is what the maze.txt looks like

Comment: "that is designed to look like a maze" can you give more description of the file? like the file format or its header and such? you could directly read from file but if you know the format then reading will be much easier

Comment: @Koushik just edited so that you can see what the maze file will look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr[X][Y];
int fd = fopen("inputFile.name", "r");
for(i=0; i< X; i++)
{
 for(j=0; j< Y; j++)
 {
   fscanf(fd, "%d", &arr[i][j]);
 }
}
```

Use fscanf to read from file, while u can use fprintf to print in file.

Comment: i don't think i'm supposed to use fopen yet